# What are the different types of responses from a Web service?

Tags: web-services

I want to know about the different types of web service responses.

Comment: What platform are you asking about? .NET or Java? WCF or ASMX? What version? Please be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the response as in "it returns 2 strings and an int" you need to look at the [WSDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) of the webservice.

Answer (score 2):

The [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) has a section on status code definitions. If this doesn't really answer your question, you may have to add more detail describing what you would like to know.